# Assigning variable to given string in java

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I'm writing a method which assigns a value to a variable with a given name, and should work something like this.

```
public void assignVariable(String varName, T val) {
        T varName = val;
}
```

Is there any way to implement something like this?

Comment: Your design is wrong... what if the string passed in is `System.out` or `java`? Just override them?

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Do you want to assign to a local variable? That's done. To a global? Declare it outside your method. Or as a class member.

Comment: You probably want your class to hold a `Map` that maps name to variable. Make a `Map<String, Object>`